# How to perform something like meteor reset on deployed app?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an app deployed on digital ocean and am trying to perform a `meteor reset` to reset the DB etc. Where is meteor located when deployed via mup? I keep getting a `command not recognized` with meteor commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know you can't run `meteor reset` on deployed apps like that as it's already been built by MUP. The way you could mimic a meteor reset is to run the mongo shell on your digital ocean server:

`mongo`

You can check what the databases are by using:

`show dbs`

and then access the one meteor is running by doing:

`use [db name]`

and then manually drop the databases by using:

`db.[collection name].drop()`

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/

Meteor already has the user collection defined so you'd probably want to drop that collection too if you want a clean start

Comment: ah tyvm. (text for minimum characters <---this needs to be changed lol)

Comment: I guess that forces you to type 'thank you very much' ha!

No problem :)